# JavaEE way to serialize object to json

Tags: json, java-ee-7

With Jackson i can create Json strings very easily:

```
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(object)
```

The problem is that this relies on specific api implementation. Is there a pure JavaEE way to achieve this?

I want to send the json via websocket. Sending via rest is no problem - specifying the mediatype is enough. Probably there is a way to create the json the same way the rest api does it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theorey, you should be able to something along the lines of:

```
@Context
private MessageBodyWorkers workers;
```

and then

```
MessageBodyWriter<MyBean> messageBodyWriter =
            workers.getMessageBodyWriter(YourBean.class, YourBean.class,
                    new Annotation[]{}, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
messageBodyWriter.writeTo(myBean, YourBean.class, YourBean.class,
    new Annotation[] {},
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
    new MultivaluedHashMap<String, Object>(),
    baos);
```

However, I have to add that it never worked for me reliably, so I ended up calling Jackson directly instead.